# Debugging C with Code::Blocks

Tags: c, debugging, codeblocks

I made my code as a standalone .c file and read that, in order to debug, the file must be in a project. So I made an empty project and added my file to it, set some breakpoints and, when i run the debugger, I get this on console:

```
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Child process PID: 13112
Error in re-setting breakpoint 2: PC register is not available
Error in re-setting breakpoint -3: PC register is not available
In  ()
```

Tried some tutorials and whatched some videos without success. Does somebody knows a fix for that? Is there a simpler way to debug a .c file?

Comment: The infromation you give is a bit sparse. Some older GDB versions (yours included) have trouble with pathnames that contain spaces and/or commas. There also was once a problem with the Solaris GDB version and debugging 32-bit app-cores with a 64-Bit GDB. Sometimes it is simpler with these IDEs to start from scratch and copy the *content*  of the files instead of importing complete files.

Comment: You suggest making another project, then?

Comment: Tried, changed path too... Nothing changed, same error.

Comment: Feared that, sorry. But those older versions are known to be a bit picky about the input so I thought it would be worth a try. Would you mind to post the culprit, that is: the file standalone.c such that we can try it out ourselves? (would need versions of compiler, Code::Blocks , OS etc., too)

Comment: I was using the MinGW version that came with Code::Blocks 16.01. I updated MinGW and now everything Works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Yepp, sometimes it is that simple ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated MinGW downloading it from its sourceforge repositor.
Downloaded the 6.2.0 version that is available in this [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/6.2.0/threads-posix/dwarf/).

Then I unziped it to C:\ and modified the environment variable Path to add the new C:\MinGW\bin folder. To know if you made it correctly just open CMD and type gcc --version.

After that, I modified the compiller and debugger settings of Code::Blocks to use the new version of MinGW and its executables.

Now it is compiling and debugging properly.

Answer (score 1):

For linux system you could use gdb as debugger in this way:

```
$ vim hello.c
# include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello \n");
}

$ gcc -o hello hello.c

$ ./hello
$ gdb hello
(gdb) break main
(gdb) run
```

and then you can use:
    c or continue
    n or next
    s or step
For more details see [this](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to Free Pascal's [GDB Debugger Tips](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/GDB_Debugger_Tips) the problem is with GDB and they cite [Bug 14018](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14018).

It appears you should use a different version of GDB. They suggest downgrading to 7.2. Now I believe other versions are now available, like 8.0. I don't know if GDB 8.0 suffers it too.